# Attaching ImageButton to OnMyLocationButtonClickListener interface in android-googlemaps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to use a custom button to change camera focus to my current location. I am using ImageButton and trying to add it to setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this) but i can't.
What should i do to use method of OnMyLocationButtonClickListener interface.

Here's the code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnMyLocationButtonClickListener {
    ...
    getMyLocation = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.getMyLocation_button);

    getMyLocation.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this); 
//gives error: setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener() is undefined
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: have u added google-play-servcies-lib as a project library ?

Comment: yes, i did. map works fine. I just want to use an image button to use method of OnMyLocationButtonClickListener interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you can add the following code to your ImageButton listener.

```
LatLong coordinates = new LatLng(yourLatitude,yourLongitude);
yourMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates,zoomLevel));
```

Comment: thanks, that works fine. I am wondering, is there any way to attach OnMyLocationButtonClickListener interface to a widget?

Comment: @RTL I'm sorry I haven't worked with Widgets. If you are new to widget you can start [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Comment: I meant widgets like Buttons, ImageButtons, TextViews, etc.

Comment: @RTL You cannot attach or set OnMyLocationButtonClickListener to any other components. Instead you can perform the same action by using the above code in the corresponding onClick event.